# Sending Responce - PHP API

Tags: php, xml, api

I have built a custom api using php, its a simple api that works by posting xml data.
The code that I have working to post to the api is:

```
<?php 
$xml_data = '<document>
 <first>'.$first.'</first>
 <last>'.$last.'</last>
 <email>'.$email.'</email>
 <phone>'.$phone.'</phone>
 <body>TEST</body>
</document>';
        $URL = "url";
        $ch = curl_init($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $Response = curl_exec($ch);    
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "Responce= ".$responce;
?>
```

On the other side, the code the above posts to:

```
<?php 
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($postdata);
$first = $xml->first;
$last = $xml->last;
$email = $xml->email;
$phone = $xml->phone;
?>
```

Then I take those php variables and send to a database.. ALL THIS CODE IS WORKING!!

But my questions is: How do I send a response back to the posting side? 
How do I use curl_init to send to curl_exec?

Any help would be great! Thank you
Jason

Comment: Why are you calling `curl_exec` twice?

Comment: Mistake, sorry! Im taking out output and the close, and leaving response and the close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
 echo "Responce= ".$Response;
                   ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

To return a response you'd do the same as you would for any other content, set a header and echo your output. For example, to return an xml response, from the script handling the post data do the following

```
<?php 
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($postdata);
$first = $xml->first;
$last = $xml->last;
$email = $xml->email;
$phone = $xml->phone;

// do your db stuff

// format response
$response = '<response>
    <success>Hello World</success>
</response>';
// set header
header('Content-type: text/xml');
// echo xml identifier and response back
echo chr(60).chr(63).'xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" '.chr(63).chr(62);
echo $response;
exit;
?>
```

You should see the response returned from `curl_exec()`